# Java mysql connects to localhost

Tags: java, mysql

I have problem with my java code.

I want to connect to my remote server, so I did that:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://188.68.252.*5:3306/";
    String dbName = "slimxaq_op**a";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "slimxaq_op**a";
    String password = "deokabe**";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I run it, I get this:

`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'slimxaq_opt**a'@'94.232.**.60' (using password: YES)`

This `ip` is my localhost adress, why does it connect to localhost when I configured it for remote server? My server is opened for remote connections.

Comment: are you sure password is the same for localhost and remote connection?

Comment: remove password and try once.

Comment: it still using my localhost adress :/ java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'slimxaq_optyka'@'94.232.33.60' (using password: NO)

Comment: it connects to 94.232.33.60 when i want to 188.68.252.*5

Comment: `*5` is no valid IP-segment.

Comment: Can you reach the MySQL Server and open the db using a database tool instead of java?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the server, but your problem is you do not have access rights. Connect with a db tool, and grant access for your IP on user slimxaq_opt**a... this should solve your problem...